# Orbit object around a specific object using glm

Tags: opengl, glm-math

In short: I have to create our solar system and specific the sun,afrodite and earth. The sun is set to the origin and the afrodite and earth are orbiting around sun (translate them). I want to create the moon which will be orbiting around the earth.

How can I rotate an object around a specific point and in this case around the center of earth? As far as I know how to rotate an object around in the origin.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a high quality answer but the basic idea is this:

1. Let the **earth** be at the origin
2. Get the moon into position via a translation *then* rotation
3. Now let the **sun** be at the origin and move the earth & moon together into place with another translation then rotation.